# Bootstrap Form Content Editor Webpart Sharepoint

Tags: form, content-editor-web-part, boot-strap

I am trying to create a form which will style nice using bootstrap to look like one of the forms in the link

[twitter bootstrap forms](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/forms-tutorial.php)

However if I add the form tag to the content editor web part I recieve an error message that says form tags are not allowed in the content editor web part.

How can I use the twitter bootstrap to style forms without this?

Comment: Have you tried the HTML Forms Web Part?

Comment: Daniel I get an error an error which says cannot retrieve properties at this time when I try using the HTML forms web part.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation (a.k.a. "feature") of the ASP.NET platform altogether.
ASP.NET platform allows a single <form> tag. It actually looks like <form runat="server">, and it's main purpose is to submit the complete page for the ASP.NET framework to process.

That being said, you can overcome this limitation by transforming any <form> tags into either <div> or <fieldset>, and changing the CSS styles to point to those tags instead of the <form> tag.

fieldset { /* copy styles from form */ }

Comment: @Codec your edit removed relevant content. You removed <fieldset> from the body of the answer,  it now reads <div> or ,. That doesn't make sense anymore. Also added a semicolon after <form> which is bad syntax. I would appreciate edits and reviews from being more careful, mostly if it's only aesthetics. By polishing the format you changed the meaning and added new syntactically wrong elements.

Comment: Sorry @amadeo next time I will be more careful

Comment: Thanks, appreciated! Can you fix the edit? Otherwise I'll flag it so that it can be fixed. Thanks

Comment: @AmadeoGallardo Click on the "edited X hours ago" link and scroll down to your original answer. Click rollback and your original answer will come back on display.